# IIS restrict access for folder to specific page

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

Is there a way to limit access to a particular page with IIS?  basically what I'm looking for is to only allow access to a particular page via another specific page/link.  I've looked into the `IP Address and Domain Restrictions` feature within IIS and can utilize that, but I would like to keep it between particular pages.

for example:

I have a page, `SecurityCheck.aspx`  and I only want a person to be able to access that page if they came from `SecurityPassThrough.aspx`.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know your experience level I think it's worth pointing out that what you're trying to do would not truly be a secure solution.  Anyone is capable of modifying their HTTP request headers before sending them to the server.

If this faux security is good enough for your purposes, then you could implement it simply by checking the `Request.UrlReferrer` property.  As far as I know there is no way to do this type of processing out of the box in IIS, so you're left going down the stack to the ASP.NET level:

```
if (!Request.UrlReferrer.Segments.Contains("SecurityPassThrough.aspx")) {
    //Do something
}
```